# Powershell Allow Parameter only if the object the function is called on has a particular property

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm wondering if it is possible to designate a parameter for a function that hides itself when the object being used has a particular property

For instance if we have

```ps
Function Do-Something
{
 Param(
  [HideIfObjectHasPropertyNamed("NoPath")]
  [string] $Path
 )    
 ...
}
```

And if i have two Objects Test1 and Test2

Test1 HAS NoPath as a property
Test2 does not

So when I write out

```ps
Test1 | Do-Something -
```

After the dash I expect Path to be completely missing from the intellisense list of possible parameters

But with this

```ps
Test2 | Do-Something -Path
```

I expect Path to be an available option

Obviously I know HideIfObjectHasPropertyNamed is not a valid parameter attribute I'm wondering if there is a way with the existing parameter attributes to accomplish the same thing.

I'm still learning the ins and outs of Powershell and all the nuances of Parameters are not known to me. If this just is not possible that's fine, it would have just made a cmdlet a little friendlier to pass along to other users.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to get this to work using dynamic parameters.

Try `get-help about_functions_advanced_parameters`.  Dynamic parameters are covered towards the end and there are some useful examples.